# The expression of elastic energy in this paper

Tags: energy, crystals, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, solid-mechanics

[Elastic properties of $\rm{Ni_{2}MnGa}$ from first-principles calculations](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925838810020384#sec0010)

Hello,
I am reading a paper investigating the linear elasticity of a crystal. However, I am a little bit confused over the expression of energy over strain of a cubic crystal:

| Phase | Strain | Parameters | $$\Delta E / V_{0}$$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Austenite | $C_{1}$ | $$\varepsilon_{1} =\varepsilon_{2} = \varepsilon_{3} = \delta$$ | $$\frac{3}{2} \cdot \left( C_{11} + 2 \cdot C_{12} \right) \cdot \delta^{2}$$ |
| Austenite | $C_{2}$ | $$\varepsilon_{1} = \delta,\, \varepsilon_{2} = -\delta,\, \varepsilon_{3} = \delta^{2} / \left( 1 - \delta^{2} \right)$$ | $$\left( C_{11} - C_{12} \right) \cdot \delta^{2} + \mathcal{O}\left( \delta^{4} \right)$$ |
| Austenite | $C_{3}$ | $$\varepsilon_{3} = \delta^{2} / \left( 1 - \delta^{2} \right),\, \varepsilon_{6} = \delta$$ | $$2 \cdot C_{44} \cdot \delta^{2} + \mathcal{O}\left( \delta^{4} \right)$$ |

These are expressed over Voigt notation.
Shouldn't the last equation be $\Delta E / V_{0} = 0.5 \cdot C_{44} \cdot \delta^{2}$?

Comment: The last time you posted this, I mentioned that the tensorial and engineering shear strains differ by a factor of two; with the squaring, this would account for a factor of four discrepancy. Does this resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the reply. I posted this again because I forgot to post the link of paper and the question was closed.